# C++ returns objects by value

Tags: c++, function, return

The topic is pretty much in the title of the question. I saw this in Meyrses book "Effective C++":

> the fact that C++ returns objects by value

What does that mean and how the C++ standard supports that message? For instanance, say that we have something like this:

```
int foo()
{
    int a = 1;
    return a;
}
```

That's pretty clear, the phrase would mean that we returns the copy of the value stored in the local variable. But consider this:

```
int& foo()
{
    int a = 1;
    return a;
}
```

A compiler should warn us about returning a reference to a local variable. How does that "returning by value fact" apply to that example?

Comment: The value returned in the second example is a pointer to a specific address of memory. The fact that address just happens to be a temporary location on the stack is incidental. (And yes a good compiler will issue a warning here)

Comment: @shuttle87: No, it's not. It's a reference, not a pointer.

Comment: @shuttle87 I'm not sure if we can talk about what's being happened in the second example, bacause I think it's UB.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't know of a way to implement references except via a hidden pointer, so you're both right.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Implementation is one thing; semantics are another. This question is about C++, not "some C++ compiler v1.2.3 on OS _x_"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'll grant your point, but that doesn't make my point irrelevant. The C++ specification was not written in a vacuum, it was generated by compiler writers who needed to consider implementation details at every step of the process. If something is undefined behavior, it's either to accommodate some bizarre machine architecture or because the implementors couldn't conceive a way of making it work consistently.

Comment: @Mark: Or because they understand the value of abstractions and see no _reason_ to impose constraints. For example, _why_ impose constraints on what happens when you dereference an arbitrary, invalid pointer? There is simply no reason to do so.

Comment: @Mark Ramsom I worked on a C++-Javascript transcompiler. Our implementation of reference is significantly different from the implementation of pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meyers is correct in the main, though you have to take that wording with a pinch of salt when dealing with references. At a certain level of abstraction, here you're passing the reference itself "by value".

But what he's really trying to say is that, beyond that, C++ passes by value by default, and that this contrasts with languages such as Java in which objects are always chucked around with reference semantics instead.

In fact, one *could* argue that the passage doesn't apply to your code at all, because the reference is not an "object".

Comment: It's reasonble to ask why... I presume that variables with automatic storage duration will be erased after returning a value. So we just have undeterminate value by the reference returned from the function. Where's UB?

Comment: @St.Antario a reference to something that no longer exists is a logical contradiction. The "undefined" part comes from the specifics of the underlying implementation.

Comment: I found this: __the return statement initializes the object or reference to be returned by copyinitialization
(8.5) from the operand.__ You could add it to the answer, maybe someone else will be able to make use of it.... That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @MarkRansom: No, it doesn't. The standard itself tell us that there are no defined semantics for a reference whose lifetime continues beyond that of its referent. Whether something is UB has nothing to do with implementation.

Comment: (Having since read your comment on the question, I concede that in some situations the committee's decision-making process is influenced by real-world concerns. But I'm talking about the language, not the way the language is made. :D)

Comment: @St.Antario: Hmm, only if you also study what "copy-initialisation" means (don't be fooled by the name: it's a complex notion!)

Comment: I understand. Specifically for the lvlalue reference, it's being explaind in 8.5.3/5. In fact, we just have a reference binded to the lvlaue in the return statement, if I understood the things correctly....

Answer (score 2):

When the book says that "C++ returns objects by value", it explains what happens when you use a "plain" class name as the return type without additional "decorations", such as ampersands or asterisks, e.g.

```
struct MyType {
    ... // Some members go here
};
MyType foo() {
    ...
}
```

In the example above `foo()` returns an object by value.

This quote should not suggest that C++ lacks other ways of returning data from a function: as you can easily construct a function that returns a reference or a pointer.

Note that returning an object by pointer or by reference creates undefined behavior only when you return a pointer or a reference to a local object. Accessing object past its lifetime always causes undefined behavior. Returning a local by reference or by pointer is perhaps the most common mistake that causes this undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Return by reference will give you a error as u are passing a reference of a variable to another function ( function which called function foo) which is beyond the scope of that local variable ( variable a).

Comment: It will _not_ "give you an error". Also, you did not answer the question.

Comment: well its a warning.. not an error. (sorry for the mistake). Even though the local variable is out of scope for the parent function but still its value is accessible.